# Convert date from 1st untill day of last month to 1'st date in month

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a lot of cell in excell table,
How can I convert any date in a month into first date of month ?

I have a lot of data like this

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
| |ITEMS |      DATE IN        | CONVERT TO FIRST OF MONTH       |  DATE_OUT       |
+-+------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
|A|ITEM 1| March 16, 2016      | March 01, 2016                  |  April 01, 2016 | 
|B|ITEM 2| March 16, 2016      | March 01, 2016                  |  April 01, 2016 |
|C|ITEM 3| January 29, 2016    | January 01, 2016                |          -      |
|D|ITEM 4| January 29, 2016    | January 01, 2016                |          -      |
+-+------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I need this, coz I want to calculate an item that have days over two months,
So, if **DATE_IN** is 01 january, the item have a free time untill march 31.

Let say, the item still not out until 20 April, **DATE OUT = -**
Then I want to print it like

```
+--------+-----------------+
| |ITEMS | DATE OVER (DAY) |      
+--------+-----------------+
| ITEM 1 |       0         |
| ITEM 2 |       0         |
| ITEM 3 |       20        |
| ITEM 4 |       20        |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of alternates that are a few characters shorter,

```
=EOMONTH(A1, -1)+1
'or,
=A1-DAY(A1)+1
```

[image: eomonth_plus_one]

Use the [EOMONTH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314FFA1-2BC9-4005-9D66-F49DB127D628) or [EDATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) function to add months.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula to round each date to the first of the month:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), 1)
```

assuming that cell `A1` contains a date in value which you want to convert.

The strategy here is to rebuild a new date using the same year and month of the original date, but using the first of the month instead of whatever the original day was.